# Cross-platform mobile development, Apache Cordova

Tags: apache, cordova, icenium

I need to write an application for iOS and Android. Don't have a need and time to write a native app, so thinking about using a cross-platform mobile development tools, such as phonegap, titanium etc. 
 Which tool should I use? I am interested in the product offered by Icenium that uses Apache Cordova framework. How is it different from Phonegap? May be there are other tools which are better? 
 Thank you!

Comment: Also, you may be interested in Xamarin, if you know C# (or Java, as C# isn't to hard to pick up if you do). I would love to learn to use it at some point, as I haven't yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer directly your question "How is Icenium different from Phonegap?", we've published a blog post: [What's the Difference Between Icenium and PhoneGap Build?](http://www.icenium.com/blog/icenium-team-blog/2013/05/01/what%27s-the-difference-between-icenium-and-phonegap-build-)

You might also be interested in: [What is Icenium Really?](http://www.icenium.com/blog/icenium-team-blog/2013/03/28/what-is-icenium-really-)

Comment: Rather than requiring people to visit your website to read this, could you summarize the relevant content within your answer? That would help prevent against the links going down or moving in the future.

Comment: Since your answer is apparently too complex to be summarized here, I'm going to go ahead and close this question as too broad.

Answer (score -2):

One big difference: The fact the Phonegap is free, whereas Icenium is not. :( That being said, I recommend using Phonegap Build from Adobe, alongside of Phonegap. It is what I use.

Icenium seems to have better integration with Visual Studio, so if that is your thing, it may be nice. I use sublime text 3, so I have yet to try the tools with both of them and Visual Studio.

Also, you may be interested in Xamarin, if you know C# (or Java, as C# isn't to hard to pick up if you do). I would love to learn to use it at some point, as I haven't yet.

Comment: From the Icenium website I understood that the back end of the application in Apache Cordova is stored on a cloud. Isn't it an advantage? Also, since you have an experience developing in phonegap, how much slower is it compared to the native app? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know about speed, as none of my apps are both native and HTML5. Also, none of my projects have gotten to production yet. For Apache Cordova backends in the cloud, I am not aware of such a feature. I know they compile in the cloud with Icenium.